# React - Files on src folder after build [Images]

Tags: reactjs, file, build

I run `npm run build` successfully and my project works as expected.  Then when I upload an image into `src/assets/images` I get an error such as:

> Cannot find module './1gvzeqijj9u4yka.png'

where `1gvzeqijj9u4yka.png` is the image I just uploaded.

I'm importing the image this way

```
src={`${require("./../../assets/images/covers/" +
       news.coverImgName)}`}
```

If I run `npm run build` again after uploading an image, everything works fine again, the image is there, and the error disappears.

I have already tried changing paths from `./../` to `../` and `/` at the end, and none of those resolved the issue.

How do I get my project to automatically include the image when I add it to the project?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid doing another `build`? Are you importing that image into your JS modules? E.g. `import image1 from 'assets/images/image1';`?

Comment: Because it's a news site, i cant rebuild the app every time someone upload an img - I edit my question, check how I'm importing the img

Comment: Alright. Instead of putting it in `src/assets/images`, you most likely have to put the images in your `public` directory outside of Webpack instead, and use `src={'/image-name.png'}` instead.

Comment: Now i have another issue, i got my 404 placeholder if i try to draw the image, BUT when it's built, again i dont get the error. :(